# /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so: invalid ELF header

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, intellij-idea, java-native-interface

Use IntelliJ IDEA to compile Android jni on ubuntu16.04, report

> `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so`: invalid ELF header

(.so files are generated by cross-compilation using NDK)

I added the this path into the /etc/ld.so.conf:

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

then run

```
sudo ldconfig
```

didn't work

My `Android.mk` is as following:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := JNIHello
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Java_com_mmeid_Test_Hello_JNIHello.c
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: What, exactly, is reporting this "invalid ELF header" error? The compilation process? The linker step? Show more output.